# Parsing SOAP response with LINQ to XML - how to get nested nodes under parent?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, soap, linq-to-xml

I have an SOAP response that looks similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <getLoginResponse xmlns="http://<remotesite>/webservices">
        <person_id>123456</person_id>
        <person_name>John Doe</person_name>
    </getLoginResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I've been able to successfully extract the `<get LoginResponse ...>` node with the following LINQ code:

```
string soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();

XNamespace ns = "http://<remotesite>/webservices";

XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(soapResult);

var respUser = (from r in xDoc.Descendants(ns + "getLoginResponse")
                select new User
                           {
                               Name = r.Element("person_name").Value
                           }).FirstOrDefault();
```

*However*, the call to `Name = r.Element("person_name").Value` gives me an `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` error.

I looked into this further, and I see that if I run this query, all of the values (person_id, person_name) are in fact in the *nested* `.Descendants().Descendants()` XElement collection:

```
var respUser = (from r in xDoc.Descendants(ns + "getLoginResponse") 
                select r).Descendants().ToList();
```

So, what this tells me is in my original LINQ query, I am not extracting the nodes under `<getLoginResponse>` correctly.

How can I combine this together, using `... select new User { ... }` to fill my custom object?

Doing something like:

```
var respUser = (from r in xDoc.Descendants(ns + "getLoginResponse").Descendants()
                select new User()
                              {
                                 Name = r.Element("person_name").Value
                              }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Doesn't work very well :)

**Thanks all for the solution - I omitted the namespace from the child elements, which caused my issue!**

Comment: there is no `display_name` element in your XML

Comment: Why are you parsing SOAP at all? Is there a reason to not use a Service Reference?

Comment: that was my mistake, changing the names of fields to protect the innocent :)

Comment: @John Saunders - I am interfacing with a third party unix service that is actually parsing the messages through a custom interface - so I don't have an actual endpoint to connect to.

Comment: If this gets too crazy, then consider creating a WCF transport for the custom interface. You could then use WCF.

Comment: @John Saunders luckily its just a handful of simple calls, so I think manually parsing the responses won't be too bad. I will check that out though, may come in handy if things do get crazy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add a valid namespace to your query, in your example that would be `"http://foobar/webservices"`, e.g.:

```
XElement xml = XElement.Load(@"testData.xml");
XNamespace foobar = "http://foobar/webservices";
string personId = xml.Descendants(foobar + "person_id").First().Value;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the namespace:

```
r.Element(ns + "person_name").Value
```